# Prevent scientific notation in html input field of type text

Tags: javascript, html, scientific-notation, input-field

It looks like assigning a value of 1000000000000000000000 is changing the field value to 1e+21, but I would like to keep it as a string i.e. 1000000000000000000000

```
<input id="high" type="text" value="1000000000000000000000">
```

Here is a screenshot of the output I see in the browser:
[Screenshot showing the 1e21 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKHnT.png)

When I tried this using jsfiddle, the text stayed intact and did not change to scientific notation. 
https://jsfiddle.net/4q1dt503/

What else could be causing this on my page?

Comment: For me, simply saving that HTML as an `.html` and opening it results in the full number. Can you post an example or page for which scientific notation is displayed, so we can try to figure out the difference?

Comment: Thanks. I can't post the link but it looks like it's some kind of plugin that's causing this. I disabled the jquery cookie plugin and the problem went away. But it couldn't be the cookie plugin so I am looking into what else could be doing it. Definitely something that's dependent on that cookie plugin... will keep you posted.

Comment: A question without a [MCVE] is off-topic for Stack Overflow - if you can't post *the* link, please post *some* code (as a snippet in the question, or on JSFiddle or something) that reproduces the problem

Comment: I will if I can reproduce the problem on jsfiddle myself. Sorry for being here.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input. I have resolved this issue. There was a custom plugin that was changing the string to integer and plugging its value in the input box.